dump базы данных neo4j
Возникает ошибка при попытке сделать dump, какие могут быть причины её возникновения? Буду очень благодарна вашей помощи.
Команда:
sudo docker run --interactive --tty --rm    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data    --volume=backups:/backups   34af4527ee58 neo4j-admin database dump neo4j --to-path=/backups

Результат:
2024-06-17 06:59:10.150+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.d.DumpCommand] Starting dump of database 'neo4j'


2024-06-17 06:59:10.451+0000 ERROR [o.n.c.d.DumpCommand] Failed to dump database 'neo4j': Unable to dump database: AccessDeniedException: /backups


2024-06-17 06:59:10.452+0000 ERROR [o.n.c.d.DumpCommand] Dump failed for databases: 'neo4j'
Dump failed for databases: 'neo4j'
Run with '--verbose' for a more detailed error message.


Версия БД community neo4j
С задачей разобралась, что-то не так с папкой выгрузки, но при отсутствии параметра --to-path neo4j самостоятельно создает папку и все получилось


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Спасибо, сообщение исправила

Ну а прав на /backups хватает?
